# Flutter unable to call callBack function for firebase cloud messing

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have got this error when I try to add callback function `onBackgroundMessage` for Flutter **firebase cloud messaging**.

flutter: The following ArgumentError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty):
flutter: Invalid argument(s): Failed to setup background message handler! `onBackgroundMessage`
flutter:           should be a TOP-LEVEL OR STATIC FUNCTION and should NOT be tied to a
flutter:           class or an anonymous function.
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   HomeScreen
flutter:   file:///Users/sournvisal/Documents/projects/flutter-project/one_sala/lib/router.dart:17:39

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As the error said the `onBackgroundMessage` needs to be **TOP-LEVEL** OR **STATIC FUNCTION**

**TOP-LEVEL function** is a function that is outside a class. example:

```
 Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
   if (message.containsKey('data')) {
     // Handle data message
     final dynamic data = message['data'];
   }

   if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
     // Handle notification message
     final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
   }

   // Or do other work.
 }
```

**STATIC FUNCTION** is a function inside a class but prefixed with `static` keyword and do not operate on an instance, and thus do not have access to `this`.
example:

```
class Fcm {
  static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
     // Handle data message
     final dynamic data = message['data'];
   }

   if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
     // Handle notification message
     final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
   }

   // Or do other work.
  }
}
```

Comment: @Wilmer You should use it like this:

`onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler`



NOT like this:

`onBackgroundMessage: (message) => myBackgroundMessageHandler(message)`

Comment: how can I access context inside myBackgroundMessageHandler ? for instance to call Provider.of<myprovider>(context) ???